# distribution certificate doesn't seem to match

Tags: ios, validation, certificate

Hi I get this error when I try to validate my application,I looked all over the internet,did everything people suggest to do.
I'm kind of new to iOS development and a little afraid to revoke my distribution certificates.
I deleted all the certificates in the keysChains and downloaded my certificates from the apple developer console,still same error.
Please help.

Comment: did you able to create an ipa file. what the error you get from apple side can you add this in your question

Comment: I can export an ipa without a problem

Comment: ok so what error exactly  you will get when you validate it

Comment: The error says no certificate found but there is a valid one in the apple center and need to install it which I did

Comment: have you add new app in your itunes connect before upload it. check in keychain have certificate valide with private key?

Comment: it has certificate with private key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115394/discussion-between-nitin-gohel-and-zach-bublil).

Comment: Share your screenshot for the xcode build settings and Keychain access.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check your `Certification` are right after it check you `provisioning profile` are correct, after it go to `xCode` and delete your developer ID and go to `Keychain access` and delete all `Certification` and restart your Mac after it set your `Certification` to `KeyChain access` and sign with your Developer ID to `xCode` after it Download your provisioning Profile and set it to xCode, restart your Mac again, after it upload your app to store.
I hope it helpful.